# Executing a batch file containing an exe path remotely via wmic

Tags: wmi, wmic

I have a batch file on Computer-A that contains several commands and a path to an exe file.

When I execute the batch file on Computer-B via wmic, I can see all the commands being executed in the batch file except that it does not run the exe. What are the things I need to check for to see why the .exe is not being executed on Computer-A?

wmic execution:

```
wmic /node:"<server_ip>" /user:domain\user /PASSWORD:"password" /OUTPUT:STDOUT process call create "cmd.exe /c C:\Folder\batch.bat"
```

Answer (score 0):

File paths in wmic need to be c style paths. So `C:\\somefolder\\somefile.ext`. `\\` for`\` in paths.

Comment: Hi@quldude and @Serenity! I think I'm having the same problem as this. I am trying to run a batch file using wmic. This batch file executes a jar file that writes to a text file in a shared folder. The text file does not get updated even though the command runs successfully thru wmic i.e. wmic returns a processID and its 0 as a return value