# Jarfile ran thru wmic does not append to file

Tags: java, windows, batch-file, cmd, wmic

I have a **jar** file that writes its logs to a **text file**. The text files are in a **shared folder** of a **server**, say **serverA**.

I wrapped the **jar** file on a **bat** file. The content of the bat file is,

```
java -jar WriteToFile.jar
```

Both the **jar** file and **bat** file are saved in my machine, say **computerA**.

I call this **bat** file from another machine, say **computerB** by using **wmic**

```
wmic /user:<username> /password:<password> /node:<machine> process call create "cmd /c D:\eclipse-java-luna-SR2-win32\Test_WriteTofile.bat"
```

The output of **wmic** is,

```
Executing Win32_Process->Create() Method execution successful.
Out Parameters: instance of __PARAMETERS
{
    ProcessId: 3476
    ReturnValue: 0
};
```

However, when I open the **text file** saved in **serverA**, the **text file** is not updated.
I tried running the **bat** files locally in **computerA** and it successfully updated the **text file** in **serverA**.

I read about [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28120566/executing-a-batch-file-containing-an-exe-path-remotely-via-wmic), and tried updating the pathname I indicated in my java program as,

```
"\\\\serverA\\SomeFolder\\SomesubFolder\\Testing\\Files\\"
```

Still, locally, when the **bat** file is ran in **computerA**, the **text file** is updated. But when ran thru **wmic** from **computerB**, the **text file** is not updated.

Note: I don't think it is the problem of **permissions**. Since I logged in **computerB** using an **administrator** account of **computerA**. I also used the same user and pass for the **wmic** command.

Comment: Get rid of the batch file and try running the Java command directly from the wmic command line. The command shell isn't adding any value here, and it may be obscuring an execution problem.

Comment: you might need an additional line in the bat that runs on server B which maps the server A . Take a look at [net use](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490717.aspx)